# Reactjs Infinite Scroll / Add data to array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, fetch, infinite-scroll

I want to implement react-infinite-scroller to my Website, but have problems with loading new data after reaching the bottom of my site. My app displays always all of my elements already at the start. It should only load the first few and then after reaching the bottom, load more elements...
Here is my
**Fetch:**

```js
loadContent() {
    var requestUrl = '//api.jsonbin.io/b/5bba8ec46d95da7b7a759251/14';
    fetch(requestUrl).then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }) .then((data, response)=>{
        this.setState({tracks : data});

    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log("There has been an error");
    });
}
```

And here I map over the array:

```js
  var items = [];
    this.state.tracks.map((title, i) => {
      items.push(

        <div key={title.id}>
      <Item
        key={title.id}
        title={title.title}/>

    </div>


        );
    });
```

And this is my return with the infinite-scroll:

```js
return (
        <InfiniteScroll
               pageStart={0}
               loadMore={this.loadContent.bind(this)}
               hasMore={this.state.hasMoreItems}
               loader={loader}
              >
              <div className="tracks" >
                {items}

              </div>
           </InfiniteScroll>

    )
```

Do you have any suggestions or help for me?
Would appreciate it :)

Best Regards

**EDIT:**

Here is what my API looks like:

```js
 [
  {
    "kik": ".",
    "telegram": ".",
    "twitter": ".",
    "slack": ".",
    "discord": ".",
    "messenger": "https://www.messenger.com/t/dontfeatit",
    "description": "We challenge you to improve you health by fasting...",
    "image": "https://botlist.co/media/17857/c/42743635_250193639002714_5041958715473788928_n-medium.jpg",
    "userId": 1,
    "title": "Don't Fucking Eat It",
    "body": "Fasting to improve your health or help feed those in need.",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "kik": ".",
    "telegram": ".",
    "twitter": ".",
    "slack": "https://fyrebox.slack.com/",
    "discord": ".",
    "messenger": "https://www.messenger.com/t/fyrebox",
    "description": "Fyrebox make...",
    "image": "https://botlist.co/media/17814/c/fyrebox-medium.jpg",
    "userId": 1,
    "title": "Fyrebox Quiz Bot",
    "body": "Create a quiz playable as a bot in Messenger and/or Slack",
    "id": 2
  }
 ]
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your `loadContents() paginates` and you're overwriting `this.state.tracks` instead of appending to it on each request `then`. Instead of `this.setState({tracks: data})`, it should be more like `this.setState({tracks: [ ...this.state.tracks. ...data]})`. This is just from preliminary glance. I don't know all the details of your API.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Do you have any examples on how to fetch Data and paginate it? This could be very helpful in this case!